# Passing path of file to another Python File in Another Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a Python file in another location that requires an image file path. Here is the file structure:

```
Main_Dir
 - main.py
 - test.jpg
 - Second_Dir
    - other.py
```

My `main.py` is calling a function in `other.py` and passing `"test.jpg"` as an argument. Obviously, `other.py` cannot see this image as it isn't in its directory. Is there a way to do this so that `other.py` uses the `test.jpg` without having to pass the absolute path?

**main.py**

```
process_image("test.jpg")
```

**other.py**

```
def process_image(image_path):
    rotate(image)
    a*b = c
    ....
```

**Error:**

```
No such file or directory: 'test.jpg'
```

Comment: If you don't pass the full path to the image file, then `process_image()` function is going to have to assume *something* — what should that be or what assumption should be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the 'absolute path' of the file, which is the full path which will work from any location on the same computer:

```
from pathlib import Path

process_image(Path("test.jpg").absolute())
```

Even better might be `.resolve()`, which will also resolve any symbolic links, and just give you the 'real' path of the object being passed.

```
process_image(Path("test.jpg").resolve())
```

However, a simple import won't change the working directory of your script - the script wouldn't simply use its own location as a reference. So, you may still have problems, if you don't start `main.py` in the folder it is actually in.

To solve that, get the location of the `main.py` script when you first start the program:

```
location = Path(__file__).parent()
my_file = (location / 'test.jpg').resolve()
process_image(my_file)
```

This works because `__file__` will contain the filename of the script it is called from, `.parent()` gets the parent folder (i.e. the folder the script is in) and the rest is the same as before. Just note that `Path('dir') / 'name.ext'` is just a nice way of constructing a path - Python allows 'dividing' a `Path` by a string to extend the path.

Note: don't worry about forward slashes you may see in a resolved path. Although Windows doesn't always support the use of forward slashes, Python functions do (unless you use a Python function to directly execute some Windows command). Forward slashes are the standard on every OS except Windows, which is why Python defaults to it - it's not a bad idea to use them for several reasons.